# To complete or to be completed?

Tags: infinitives

It took so long years **to complete**

It took so long years **to be completed**

Which is right? Both are okay?

Comment: The fragments in **bold** are both fine. The first is "active voice" and the second is "passive voice." They mean the same thing. But "so long years" is wrong. Maybe you meant "so many years" but it depends on exactly what you're trying to say.

Comment: I think you should put that as an answer